# Woocommerce my account screen edit username

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I've setup a Woocommerce site & allowed users to register with a username, however in their account details screen which allows them to change their password, add a first name, etc they cannot edit their username. Is there a way to add this functionality? Seems silly to allow people to register with a username but not being able to change it afterwards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Woocommerce is a plugin for WordPress, and as such, defaults to WordPress behavior for user names in that non-administrators can't change a user name after creating an account. Lower level users changing usernames would break all kinds of things, esp. in an ecommerce situation. Be glad they can't.

There are several plugins that allow an *administrator* to change user names; that's a much safer way to do things. Search https://wordpress.org/plugins/

Comment: Thanks fro the answer - I didn't realise having them change usernames would cause issues. Do you know of any sites that explain it in more detail? I've gotten a bit curious about it now that you've mentioned potential problems.

Comment: As I said, changing a username will break all kinds of things: orders, database transients, payments. Besides, it's terrible UX; you allow the end user as little power and as few options possible.